# What is the difference between "? extends E" and "T extends E"?

Tags: java, generics, collections, subtyping

I am new to java and am trying to understand the curious syntax below from Java Generics and Collections book.. (I worked extensively with C++ templates and hence can claim to understand the basics of generic programming and the probable gotchas):

```
interface Collection <E> {
  ...
  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
  ...
}
```

Why can't the above be written as:

```
interface Collection <E> {
  ...
  public boolean addAll(Collection<T extends E> c);
  ...
}
```

What is the difference? Is it just the language restriction or is there any difference under the hood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be written as

```
 public <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c)
```

but there would be no point.  There's no need to name that parameter.

Comment: You mean `public <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c);`

Comment: I downvoted this to bring your attention towards my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

That would make sense if the method would return something of type T. Then you could match both types. But as it just returns a boolean, you don't need to do that. Then there is no need to set a name T and it remains just as a question mark.

Let's say addAll takes a filter:

```
public <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c, Predicate<T> aFilter);
```

Now you know that the Predicate has a generic type that can operate on the collection c.